# jQuery plugins - is it a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Hey,
I am reading about js, jquery & dom from few weeks but today i read a [**Tutorial**](http://buildinternet.com/2009/02/how-to-make-an-impressive-animated-landscape-header-with-jquery/) in which he uses plugin for delay & ease.

Is it a good practice to use plugin?

*Addition to it :*

The delay.js code is finished between four to five lines.
Maybe we could also just write it.

Please help me to understand it.
Thanks.

Comment: Post the code to help us to make you understand.

Comment: @herbalessence ,please visit the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they add value to your work, I guess there's nothing wrong of use of plugin in js.
Look at the jquery's [Summary and Best Practises](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Summary_and_Best_Practices).

See this below links. They'll clear your doubt.

- [Plugin in js - a good practise ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800459/is-it-considered-bad-practice-or-unethical-to-append-always-used-small-jquery-plu)
- [Too many jquery plugins ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773109/too-many-jquery-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, plugins are an important part of jquery. You can find most of them in http://plugins.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the overhead of loading extra files, consider using a content delivery network such as Google Libraries (http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/).

They will take care of the heavy lifting for you, and you increase the odds of a visitor already having a cached copy.

Answer (score -1):

The only downside is the slight performance hit in loading one extra URL.